# How to find if there is a match in a certain time interval between two different date fields SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a column in my fact table that defines whether a Supplier is old or new based on the following case-statement:

```
CASE
             WHEN (SUBSTRING([Reg date], 1, 6) = SUBSTRING([Invoice date], 1, 6) 
             THEN ('New supplier')
             ELSE('Old supplier')
END as [Old/New supplier]
```

So for example, if a Supplier was registered 201910 and Invoice date was 201910 then the Supplier would be considered a 'New supplier' that month. Now I want to calculate the number of Old/New suppliers for each month by doing an distinct count on Supplier no, which is not a problem. The last step is where it gets tricky, now I want to count the number of New/Old suppliers over a 12-month period(if there has been a match on Invoice date and reg date in any of the lagging 12 months). So I create the following mdx expression:

```
aggregate(parallelperiod([D Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Year],1,[D Time].[Year-Month-Day].currentmember).lead(1) : [D Time].[Year-Month-Day].currentmember ,[Measures].[Supplier No Distinct Count])
```

The issue I am facing is that it will count Supplier no "1234" twice since it has been both new and old during that time period. What I wish is that, if it finds one match it would be considered a "New" Supplier for that 12- month period.

[image]

This is how the result ends up looking but I want it to be zero for "Old" since Reg date and Invoice date matched once during that 12-month period it should be considered new for the whole Rolling 12 month on 201910

[image]

Any help, possible approaches or ideas are highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Comment: do you want mdx only or sql is fine as well? Also how is your 12 month period is defined. I mean do you get something like 2 variables 201811 and 201912?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Either one is fine, I just want to find a possible solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate first at the supplier level and then at the type level:

```
select type, count(*)
from (select supplierid,
             (case when min(substring(regdate, 1, 6)) = min(substring(invoicedate, 1, 6))
                   then 'new' else 'old'
              end) as type
      from t
      group by supplierid
     ) s
group by type;
```

Note:  I assume your date columns are in some obscure string format for your code to work.  Otherwise, you should be using appropriate date functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount
FROM Facts
WHERE Regdate BETWEEN(olddate, newdate) OR InvoiceDate BETWEEN(olddate, newdate) 
GROUP BY
 Supplier
```

The above query will return all the suppliers within that time period and then group them. Thus COUNT(*) will only include unique subscribers.

You might wanna change the WHERE clause because I didn't quite understand how you are getting the 12 month period. Generally if your where clause returns the suppliers within that time period(they don't have to be unique) then the group by and count will handle the rest.

Comment: The reason for mdx is to get Rolling 12-month i.e 201910 would be (201811-201910) and 201909 would be (201810-201909) etc. So if Supplier has been New during any of the related months of that time period it would count as New for the whole period not only for that month that it matches.